# OPC UAFX Write or Read directly to/from Parent node

Tags: opc-ua

I want to write a byte array (256) to a parent node without writing each byte to the single node. The same for reading, i want to read the parent node into a byte array without collecting values from all childnodes (256). Is this possible. Below the structure ...
[opc-ua client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3X3f.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general sense, yes it should be possible.

Unfortunately it seems this server you are connected to is not implemented correctly and is returning a null value for the "Payload" array.

Comment: thx, i will contact server owner to solve this problem